# Push QML ChartView updates from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to adapt the [Qt5.9 QML Oscilloscope example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-example.html) to have the graph data pushed from c++ rather than requested from QML. Below are the pertinent sections from the QML Oscilloscope example.

datasource.h:

```
#ifndef DATASOURCE_H
#define DATASOURCE_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCharts/QAbstractSeries>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QQuickView;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class DataSource : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataSource(QQuickView *appViewer, QObject *parent = 0);

Q_SIGNALS:

public slots:
    void generateData(int type, int rowCount, int colCount);
    void update(QAbstractSeries *series);

private:
    QQuickView *m_appViewer;
    QList<QVector<QPointF> > m_data;
    int m_index;
};

#endif // DATASOURCE_H
```

datasource.cpp:

```
#include "datasource.h"
#include <QtCharts/QXYSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QAreaSeries>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QtMath>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QAbstractSeries *)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QAbstractAxis *)

DataSource::DataSource(QQuickView *appViewer, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_appViewer(appViewer),
    m_index(-1)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSeries*>();
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractAxis*>();

    generateData(0, 5, 1024);
}

void DataSource::update(QAbstractSeries *series)
{
    if (series) {
        QXYSeries *xySeries = static_cast<QXYSeries *>(series);
        m_index++;
        if (m_index > m_data.count() - 1)
            m_index = 0;

        QVector<QPointF> points = m_data.at(m_index);
        // Use replace instead of clear + append, it's optimized for performance
        xySeries->replace(points);
    }
}

void DataSource::generateData(int type, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    // Remove previous data
    m_data.clear();

    // Append the new data depending on the type
    for (int i(0); i < rowCount; i++) {
        QVector<QPointF> points;
        points.reserve(colCount);
        for (int j(0); j < colCount; j++) {
            qreal x(0);
            qreal y(0);
            switch (type) {
            case 0:
                // data with sin + random component
                y = qSin(3.14159265358979 / 50 * j) + 0.5 + (qreal) rand() / (qreal) RAND_MAX;
                x = j;
                break;
            case 1:
                // linear data
                x = j;
                y = (qreal) i / 10;
                break;
            default:
                // unknown, do nothing
                break;
            }
            points.append(QPointF(x, y));
        }
        m_data.append(points);
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QtCore/QDir>
#include "datasource.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Qt Charts uses Qt Graphics View Framework for drawing, therefore 
QApplication must be used.
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView viewer;

    // The following are needed to make examples run without having to install the module
    // in desktop environments.
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    QString extraImportPath(QStringLiteral("%1/../../../../%2"));
#else
    QString extraImportPath(QStringLiteral("%1/../../../%2"));
#endif
    viewer.engine()->addImportPath(extraImportPath.arg(QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath(),
                                  QString::fromLatin1("qml")));
    //QObject::connect(viewer.engine(), &QQmlEngine::quit, &viewer, &QWindow::close);

    viewer.setTitle(QStringLiteral("QML Oscilloscope"));

    DataSource dataSource(&viewer);
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataSource", &dataSource);

    viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/qmloscilloscope/main.qml"));
    viewer.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    viewer.setColor(QColor("#404040"));
    viewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

ScopeView.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.1

ChartView {
    id: chartView
    animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
    property bool openGL: true
    property bool openGLSupported: true
    onOpenGLChanged: {
        if (openGLSupported) {
            series("signal 1").useOpenGL = openGL;
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (!series("signal 1").useOpenGL) {
            openGLSupported = false
            openGL = false
        }
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisY1
        min: -1
        max: 4
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 1024
    }

    LineSeries {
        id: lineSeries1
        name: "signal 1"
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY1
        useOpenGL: chartView.openGL
    }

    Timer {
        id: refreshTimer
        interval: 1 / 60 * 1000 // 60 Hz
        running: true
       repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            dataSource.update(chartView.series(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than using the Timer in QML, I'd like to use an existing Timeout in a c++ class to push new data to the QML ChartView. I have two questions:

1. How would I achieve this for the QML Oscilloscope example posted above?
2. What format would be most suitable for the c++ data to facilitate this? I'm thinking a QVector of some sort; the data will be an integer or float with a vector index.

Comment: Do you want to send it to update from C ++ for example with a QTimer instead of the QML Timer?

Comment: Using the Oscilloscope files as an example, I'd like to have a Timeout function in DataSource.cpp which calls DataSource::update(), rather than the QML Timer calling update().

Comment: You could place this file to work with this example.

Comment: I'm sorry @eyllanesc I don't quite follow?

Comment: What do you mean by `Oscilloscope files`?

Comment: The example files I've included in my original post/question. How would I replace the QML Timer function with a c++ QTimer function in the datasource.cpp excerpt included in my original question? The source files for each of the excerpts I've included is linked in the first sentence in my question.

Comment: Okay I understand, I thought you wanted to use the data generated by a real oscilloscope to take as a source for the graph.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't make that particularly clear :)

Comment: and could you explain your second question?

Comment: Why do not you want to use `QVector<QPointF>` as the example shows?

Comment: I'm more than happy to use QVector<QPointF>, I just wanted to confirm that this was a suitable/efficient approach.

Comment: `QXYSeries` accepts that type of data as input, even if you have other types of data you will have to convert it.

Comment: Ok understood. The question then becomes, how can I call update() at the end of generateData(), given that it requires a QAbstractSeries to be passed to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say in a comment you need to pass a series, then we create a method that receives the series and saves it in a member of the C ++ class, We also create a QTimer, and we do the same to update the interval:

***.h**

```
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void setSeries(QAbstractSeries *series);
    Q_INVOKABLE void setInterval(int interval);
    [...]
private:
    QXYSeries *mSeries;
    QTimer *timer;
    [...]
```

***.cpp**

```
void DataSource::setSeries(QAbstractSeries *series)
{
    if (series) {
        mSeries = static_cast<QXYSeries *>(series);
    }
}
```

Then we remove the update argument and use mSeries:

```
DataSource::DataSource(QQuickView *appViewer, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_appViewer(appViewer),
    m_index(-1)
{
    [...]
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &DataSource::update);
    timer->start(1 / 60 * 1000 );
}

void DataSource::update()
{
    if (mSeries) {
        m_index++;
        if (m_index > m_data.count() - 1)
            m_index = 0;

        QVector<QPointF> points = m_data.at(m_index);
        // Use replace instead of clear + append, it's optimized for performance
        mSeries->replace(points);
    }
}

void DataSource::setInterval(int interval)
{
    if(timer){
        if(timer->isActive())
            timer->stop();
        timer->start(interval);
    }
}
```

***.qml**

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    dataSource.setSeries(chartView.series(0));
    if (!series("signal 1").useOpenGL) {
        openGLSupported = false
        openGL = false
    }
}
[...]
function changeRefreshRate(rate) {
    dataSource.setInterval(1 / Number(rate) * 1000);
    //refreshTimer.interval = 1 / Number(rate) * 1000;
}
```

You can find the complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/47723954).

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't receive any errors when running your version, but I don't receive a plot either (blank ChartView)? The update() function is being called, but it appears to fail the if (mSeries) logic every time.

Comment: How weird. although I had a small error that I just corrected it should work. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: You could check if setSeries is called. Are you using my code?

Comment: I'm using 5.9.2; yes I'm using your code. I just re-tried and it appears to be working perfectly. Thanks again! I'll go through it now in detail to understand exactly how it works.